# pgrep -t not working on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I'm on MacOS, and I'm trying to kill a script based on which terminal it is running.

I naturally gravitated towards `pkill -t ttys006 git`, but when I run that nothing works (even though I know `ttys006` is there).

I then tried to run `pgrep -t ttys006 git` and I get nothing back from pgrep. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.  `pgrep -t ` without any patterns works fine.  But shows no output when a valid pattern is passed.

Comment: So you're seeing the same issue as well?

Comment: Yes.  I am on Sierra.

Comment: pkill does not work as expected in mac. what you can do is you can run:`ps -a` to list the commands in respective TTYs, then `pgrep git` to get the PID and then run `kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: That much is fine, but I'd like to narrow down the PID to the one that is running in a specific `tty`. How do I do that without `pgrep/pkill`?

Comment: @FelipeRocha, `ps -a` will sow you that

Comment: @FelipeRocha did it give what you wanted?

Comment: I ended up installing the `proctools` package from `brew` and that actually installed a version of `pgrep` that works better... The thing I'm trying to do is still not working, but it's not because of `pgrep` anymore